# Making a table's display dependent on the selection in another table in Interface Builder

Tags: cocoa, core-data, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings, nstableview

I've got a window set up with two NSTableViews.  In Core Data I have two entities set up, one of them containing members of the other, larger grouping (e.g. `cars` and `manufacturers`).  I've got entry pages set up for each entity and they play nicely there (no faulting when trying to select from a many-to-one in a drop menu).  What I'm trying to do now is take that one step further so that when I select a `manufacturer` in the main `NSTableView`, the list of `cars` related to that `manufacuturer` will appear in the second `NSTableView`.

I've tried using bindings similar to what I've done for the `manufacturer` popup button, feeding the value from the `cars` entity, however it's simply showing a list of all the `car` entries, regardless of which `manufacturer` I select.  I don't see any options for a predicate to filter it, however, and if I set the binding's key path to `manufacturer.cars`, it shows a relationship fault.  How can I filter what gets displayed in the child table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have two NSArrayControllers. Bind the `contentArray` of the cars controller to the manufacturers controller; the controller key is `selection` (i.e., the selected manufacturer), and the model key path is that of the property containing the manufacturer's cars.

Then, bind the cars table view's columns to properties of the cars controller's `arrangedObjects`.

Comment: I'm trying this, but all it's doing is causing the edit pages to not display their content properly, and any selections on the master/children display to blip away right after being clicked.  Is there a step along the way here that needs double-checking?

Comment: Yes, check the model key paths carefully. They should look something like "selection.name" or "selection.brand". In fact, check all names: for instance, is the entity really called manufacturer and not manufacturers? Also, check the relationship in the data model: is cars a one-to-many relationship, is it required?

Comment: `selection` should be the controller key, not part of the model key path.